# Generate unique initial strings from array of strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have a very long array of strings. For example:

```
["Abyssal Specter", "Air Elemental", "Aladdin's Ring", "Ambition's Cost", "Anaba Shaman", "Angel of Mercy", "Angelic Page", "Archivist", "Ardent Militia", "Avatar of Hope", "Aven Cloudchaser","Aven Fisher"]
```

Now this array must be passed to a method which should return

```
[["Abyssal Specter","Ab"], ["Air Elemental", "Ai"], ["Aladdin's Ring","Al"], ["Ambition's Cost","Am"], ["Anaba Shaman","Ana"], ["Angel of Mercy","Angel "], ["Angelic Page","Angeli"], ["Archivist","Arc"], ["Ardent Militia","Ard"], ["Avatar of Hope","Ava"], ["Aven Cloudchaser","Aven C"],["Aven Fisher","Aven F"]]
```

The method should return the unique initials of each string in the array.

For instance, `"Abyssal Specter"` should return `"Ab"` as there is no other string starting with `"Ab"`. Similarly for `"Air Elemental"` to `"Ai"`. But `"Aven Cloudchaser"` should return `"Aven C"`, as there is a string `"Aven Fisher"`. In short, it should just generate the unique string initials.

Comment: you shell create all rules to on how to resolve the conflicts, if `Aven C` is used already, whe the next rule be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abbrev in Standard Lib does exactly that:

```
require 'abbrev'

ar = ["Abyssal Specter", "Air Elemental", "Aladdin's Ring", "Ambition's Cost", "Anaba Shaman", "Angel of Mercy", "Angelic Page", "Archivist", "Ardent Militia", "Avatar of Hope", "Aven Cloudchaser","Aven Fisher"]
p ar.abbrev.invert.to_a

# [["Abyssal Specter", "Ab"], ["Air Elemental", "Ai"], ["Aladdin's Ring", "Al"], ["Ambition's Cost", "Am"], ["Anaba Shaman", "Ana"], ["Angel of Mercy", "Angel "], ["Angelic Page", "Angeli"], ["Archivist", "Arc"], ["Ardent Militia", "Ard"], ["Avatar of Hope", "Ava"], ["Aven Cloudchaser", "Aven C"], ["Aven Fisher", "Aven F"]]
```